# How can I remove the '?' in the URL from GET?

Tags: html

I have a simple textbox

```
<form action="http://www.google.com" method="get">
Something <input type="text" name="something">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

If I enter something into the input this will be the URL `https://www.google.com/?something=something2` - in this case `something2` is what the user types.
But I want to see the URL like this `https://www.google.com/something=something2`

I've tried with `.htaccess` but I've failed.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .*  /%{QUERY_STRING}? [L]
```

Comment: Add the code you have tried with :)

Comment: Try reading through this:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11099502/htaccess-rewitecond-query-string-with-2-variable-and-rewrite-properly][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11099502/htaccess-rewitecond-query-string-with-2-variable-and-rewrite-properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this ? is coming because of method="get" in form, if you change it to POST so you are going to get data hiden not in URL, the other point to get "something=something2" in URL you have to use java script to change the action of this form by appending your part, and this java script can be existed in:

onBlur of text field

onClick of Submit

onSubmit of Form but you have ti handle submit by your self

Comment: Thanks, this seems a bit easier to deal with! :)

Answer (score 3):

There's *one* standard how query parameters have to look in a URL and that's by separating them with a `?`. The browser only knows this standard and adheres to it.

If you want a custom URL schema which does not use query parameters, build the URL yourself using Javascript upon form submit or redirect on the server-side to make the URL look the way you want.

The `RewriteRule` you have there is for *internally rewriting* the URL, it does not change how the URL looks to the client. You'll have to issue a *redirect* from the server for that to happen, which would look like this:

1. browser submits form using standard query parameters: `example.com/foo?bar=baz`
2. server responds with rewritten URL: `Location: /foo/bar=baz`
3. client repeats request to `example.com/foo/bar=baz`

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why you want to do that, however you need to do two things:

1. Prevent the default behaviour of the browser which submits the URL in that way when you use `GET`
2. Write a proper `.htaccess` file to handle that

To perform the first thing, add an event handler to the `onsubmit` event on the form, prevent default behaviour and then redirect the user to your URL that you want to use by appending the values from the inputs.

The second thing can be achieved by using Rewrite Rules.

Answer (score -2):

I may be wrong, but I don't think you can.  The '?' is telling the URL that what follows in a querystring.  At least not for unencrypted data you are passing.  Password/Username are a different story of course.

Comment: Have you guys never heard of URL rewrites?

Comment: @MMM url rewrites are server side thing, it doesn't have anything to do with what the browser sends. You cannot change that if browser handles the submit, so the only option is to prevent it from happening and construct the url manually.

Comment: Of course they're a server side thing, but the server doesn't really care what you send it. You can send it `domain.com/666hello`, and the server may read the first 3 digits, then the string and serve some content based on that. You said one can't do it but it is possible. Also, your answer seems a bit ambiguous ("at least not for unencrypted data", "password/username are a different story" etc.)